# new wordpress site spam within 2 minutes of going live?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, spam

I have recently noticed that within a few minutes of installing a WordPress site I am receiving the typical

'we can help you gina more visitors' spam messages.

**This is across multiple installs with different domain names etc.**

I can handle the spam no problem I am just wondering where they are getting the information from?

I am talking literally minutes - the site not indexed in Google or anywhere else.

I thought it might have been my server but on different servers same thing, I thought it might have been my PC (malware) but different PC same thing.

Is there some central list or some specific search term that shows newly installed WordPress themes?

If so - how would I go about disabling submission to that list (which file(s) would I need to go to?)

Thanks

Comment: Comments or other suspicious content?

Comment: There are a lot of such spammers, which gain information about such installations (either crawl or other source). The WordPress team have a paid plugin named **Aximet**, which is meant to catch various spam problems. This plugin comes integrated with WP install.

Comment: Or use the free (for non-commercial use) Akismet plugin.

Comment: Thanks both - but I have the plugin activated as well as some third party ones, I can deal with the spam - however i am trying to remove the root cause of the problem (as @Rolice said - 'other source') - I am trying to work out how they are finding the site in the first place when Google hasn't found it yet?

Comment: I suspect some incorrect (internal) practice with these spammers, showing of a day after you enable search engines. However, they supply you with WP for free, so it is fair enough..

Comment: Hacked Wordpress sites are big business. Read [Krebs on Security  Wordpress coverage](https://krebsonsecurity.com/tag/wordpress/) and  background on the [uses and value of a hacked computer](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/10/the-scrap-value-of-a-hacked-pc-revisited/) to make your blood run cold.